# VBScript to modify email content type

Tags: email, vbscript, smtp

I have incoming email set up for SharePoint 2010, and am sending forms from InfoPath using that method, with SMTP server set up on the SharePoint Server machine.  It seems easier than elevating the permissions of an anonymous user with the InfoPath code-behind option.  I also tried a custom method of sending the emails but was unable to find a way to send the form data along with the email message using the InfoPath 2010 code-behind option.  So, I found another way, using the advice from [SharePoint UK](http://sharepoint-uk.blogspot.com/2008/03/wss-emailing-itself-x-mailer-windows.html?showComment=1364573505999#c4245325941450576181)'s website.

My problem is that while removing the x-mailer header actually solved my problem regarding whole email messages, it did not allow the attached form data to be sent to the library.  The message would be imported and then just disappear if I did not have the "Save original e-mail" setting enabled.  Inspecting messages in the drop folder I found they had a content type of "multipart/related" and if I edited them with NotePad++ I could change that to "multipart/mixed" and the attached form data would then be imported as desired.

So I went about trying to modify the VB Script to make this happen BUT now nothing happens with the script at all.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong with it and VBScript really isn't my area of expertise.  Maybe it's just not possible to edit those fields or maybe I need to attack it from a different angle.  How can I get my VBScript to edit the content type for these emails?

CODE:

```
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.LogEvent 4, "starting mail filter"
    if instr(iMsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type"), "related") > 1 then
        Dim logMsg = "Mail Type:  " & iMsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type")
        Dim tempType = Replace(iMsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type"), "related", "mixed")
        shell.LogEvent 4, iMsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type")
        iMsg.Fields.Delete("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type")
        iMsg.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type") = tempType
        iMsg.Fields.Update
        shell.LogEvent 4, iMsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type")
    end if
    shell.LogEvent 4, "end mail filter"
    iMsg.DataSource.Save
    EventStatus = 0
```

Comment: maybe a comment explaining the downvote would be nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this in greater detail and found that the content-type property of an email message is one of the many that is read-only using this particular vbscript library.  So, I would have to find some other way of editing the file, and the work involved is more than what it would take to find an alternate solution that skipped email altogether.  Therefore, I am abandoning the plan of using email in this case.  If you take something away from this, let it be that there are read-only properties for the mail message object in this script.